Python Iterating over Numpy Tile and for-loops
Goal: Here is a sample of a dataset that has "ID", "PHASENAME", "CDAYS", "MULTI_FACTOR", "DAY_COUNTER", and "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT". I was able to get the code to expand to 100 days for one "ID", "PHASENAME", "CDAYS" but now I need to expand it to handle different "ID", "PHASENAME", "CDAYS" combinations.
For example BAR worked for 14 days and their labor percentage is recorded for each day. Instead of have 14 days of labor, I want to have 100 days of labor and stretch out the labor percent ( formulae = New_labor_percent = DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT * ((1/Multi_Factor)*(1/Multi_Factor)). This can be seen in the final dataset, out.
I posted a similar question which helped me with the initial expansion Python Apply function to create new rows in loop and I was able to figure out the new_labor for-loop section.
Looking for

Help with adding in the additional two datasets now. Each "ID", "PHASENAME", "CDAYS" combo should be expanded to 100 days and have its own new_labor. When I replaced df with combined_df , it was limited to 100 rows. I should have 300 rows. Should I create a for loop for the numpy.tile? Also, how should I edit my for new_labor for-loop?

UPDATES

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
last) Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 result = pd.concat([
2     expand_and_process_group(group)
3     for _, group in combined_df.groupby(['ID', 'PHASENAME', 'C_DAYS'])
4 ])
Cell In[13], line 2
1 result = pd.concat([
----> 2     expand_and_process_group(group)
3     for _, group in combined_df.groupby(['ID', 'PHASENAME', 'C_DAYS'])
4 ])
Cell In[12], line 17
15 counter += 1
16 new_labor = labor_values[indices] * ((1 / multi_factor_values[indices]) ** 2)
---> 17 if counter % multi_factor_values[indices] == 0:
18     counter = 0
19     multi_factor_values[indices] +=1
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

data={
    "ID": [ "BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR"],
    "PHASENAME": [ "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C"],
    "C_DAYS": [ 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0],
    "Multi_Factor": [7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857],
    "DAY_COUNTER": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT": [1.0,5.0,9.0,11.0,10.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,8.0,10.0,8.0,7.0,4.0,0.0],
    }

data2={
    "ID": [ "BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR"],
    "PHASENAME": [ "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"],
    "C_DAYS": [ 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0],
    "Multi_Factor": [6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667,6.666666667],
    "DAY_COUNTER": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
    "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT": [4.0,6.5,6.5,7.0,7.5,8.5,8.5,9.5,7.0,6.5,7.0,7.5,6.0,6.0,2.5],
    }

data3={
    "ID": [ "FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO","FOO",],
    "PHASENAME": [ "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"],
    "C_DAYS": [ 16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0],
    "Multi_Factor": [6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,],
    "DAY_COUNTER": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
    "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT": [1.0,2.0,7.0,7.0,10.0,10.0,9.0,10.0,6.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,8.0,6.0,2.0,0.0],
    }


df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df_b=pd.DataFrame(data2)
df_c=pd.DataFrame(data3)

combined_df= pd.concat([df,df_b,df_c])

# to get day counter to 100 using tile to extend days. will adjust labor percent at the bottom
n = 100
first_day = df["DAY_COUNTER"].iloc[0]

rep = np.tile(df.values, (n // len(df) + 1, 1))
out = pd.DataFrame(rep, columns=df.columns).iloc[:n]

out["DAY_COUNTER"] = range(first_day, n + first_day)



def expand_and_process_group(group, target_days=100):
    n = target_days
    cycle_length = int(group['C_DAYS'].iloc[0])
    counter = 0
    # Expand the group
    rep = np.tile(group.values, (n // len(group) + 1, 1))
    expanded = pd.DataFrame(rep, columns=group.columns).iloc[:n]

    # Update DAY_COUNTER
    expanded["DAY_COUNTER"] = range(1, n + 1)

    # Calculate new_labor
    labor_values = group['DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT'].values
    multi_factor_values = group['Multi_Factor'].values
    indices = (np.arange(n) % cycle_length).astype(int)
    for i in range(len(group)):
        counter += 1
        new_labor = labor_values[indices] * ((1 / multi_factor_values[indices]) ** 2)
        if counter % multi_factor_values[indices] == 0:
            counter = 0
            multi_factor_values[indices] +=1
            labor_values[indices] +=1

    expanded['new_labor'] = new_labor
    expanded = expanded.drop(['DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT'], axis=1)

    return expanded


# Process each group separately and concatenate the results
result = pd.concat([
    expand_and_process_group(group)
    for _, group in combined_df.groupby(['ID', 'PHASENAME', 'C_DAYS'])
])

# Reset the index of the final result
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)

print(result)
print(f"Total rows: {len(result)}")

